# Add-in for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am just about to get used with Visual Studio 2010 right now.

So could you mention visual studio add-in that is ready for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757357/visual-studio-2010-recommended-extensions

Comment: @Soner my question is 10 months earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look within Visual Studio itself: Tools -> Extension Manager.

This will show various tools and other extensions from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/. I'm not sure if it's working very well right now, as I'm having connection issues within VS and the site seems a bit slow.

I know AnkhSVN exists on there and I'm sure others do as well.

Here's a blog post with some more information: [Get VS2010 Extensions easily with built-in Extension Manager (and checking out a VS2010T4 editor)](http://blogs.devsource.com/devlife/content/net_general/vs2010_vsx_and_t4_editor.html)

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains has preview builds of [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+for+Visual+Studio+2010+(Preview)) available.  It may not be completely stable yet, but some ReSharper is better than no ReSharper...

Comment: Sweet ... thank you! R# is the business; wasn't aware preview build was yet available

Comment: Oh! so they have one which compatible with 2010.

Answer (score 1):

AnkhSVN - a subversion client is VS 2010 compatible.

Hope that helps,

Dan

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

Answer (score 1):

My addin [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) provides automatic DocXml/Doxygen comment generation tool for use in C/C++/C#/VB/Java. It supports XML Documentation, Doxygen, JavaDoc, and Qt format comments.

An alternative for documenting in XML format for C#/VB is [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) - there is a [feature comparison here](http://www.atomineerutils.com/compare.php) to give an idea of how they measure up to each other.

Comment: I don't mean to hound this, but it's good to be transparent and tell the community that you're the developer of said product. That being said, I "am" considering moving away from GhostDoc and giving yours a try.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: You're quite right. When I originally wrote this reply my addin was free, so I didn't think my authorship was relevant. However, as I now charge a small amount for it, I've updated the post to clarify that my post is biased.

Answer (score 1):

Get ReSharper. It really helps you make fewer errors and code faster. http://twi.im/oW