# Top Visual Studio 2010 C/C++ Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

What are your must-have extensions for VS2010 development in C/C++? I'm not looking for anything related to C#, ASP.NET, etc. Just things that are related to old-fashioned C/C++ work. Or things that have universal appeal.

The two extensions I'm using right now are:

- [H3 Viewer](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/viewer) (free, makes Help usable, sort of)
- [Visual Assist X](http://wholetomato.com) ($$$ but worth every penny. Intellisense as it should have been. This is not a plug, I'm just a customer of theirs with a few hundred licenses.)

Anything else out there? Note to close voters: there was a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757357/visual-studio-2010-recommended-extensions) 7 months ago. It's 1) outdated, 2) way too noisy. You can't "recommend" 40 extensions. 3) Generic and not related to C/C++. Resharper may be cool but I have zero interest in managed code.

Comment: Shopping advice is off-topic.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: How is that blog post relevant to the question being asked? My question is about making life easier in VS when doing C/C++ work. Pretty much on-topic I think,

Comment: by the way why do you have hundreds of licenses? ... just curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two extensions that I've come across recently and find really useful are:

- [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) subversion plug in for VS10.
- [CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/) easy to use document comparing.

Both are great to use on their own but work even better together, and best of all they're free :)