# List of Open Source Visual Studio Extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, open-source

There is a definitive list of open source visual studio extensions?

Comment: Do you specifically want open source extensions, or just free ones?

Comment: I am looking just for open source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: [Visual Studio 2010 - recommended extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757357/visual-studio-2010-recommended-extensions)

Answer (score -2):

See the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) and filter your search by price.