# Unable to install a useuable version of Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have been using Visual Studio 2015 Community version with Windows 10 for several months now. Then it unexpectedly stopped working. I am unable to open an existing solution or create a new solution without getting the following error:

[image]

I have uninstalled VS2015 and download a new installer multiple times. Upon re-installation I continuously get the following alert:

[image]

The new install will run, but when I try to open an existing solution or create a new one, I get the same error message as shown above. I have no idea what is going on here, or why VS 2015 just stopped working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I should have search a bit more before posting this question. I was able to find a solution here: [Visual Studio freezes or hangs on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703139/visual-studio-freezes-or-hangs-on-startup)

What worked for me was:

1. Launch **Command Prompt**
2. `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\`
3. `devenv.exe /ResetUserData`

I'm not sure why this worked, but my VS 2015 seems to be working correctly now.