# visual studio 2015 installed but didn't responsing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, settings, start-page

I want to set the .net core environment of my visual studio 2015. According to adam freeman first I have to update visual studio then to install .net core mvc.  I tried to update but failed then I uninstall the setup but at the last steps of uninstalling a message display the program crash such that please debug or close the program i close the program. i feel its not completely uninstalled so i go my admin drive program files and other locations where i see the visual studio files/folder and deleted these folder including visual studio 2015 and 2010. then i start to again installing visual studio after completion of installation i clicked on launch then it did ask about general settings theme etc and show the start page which didn't response. I am not able to select an option from tool bar or start new project even to close or minimise etc only close through task bar so what i have to do to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi did you try uninstalling visual studio completely from your PC? You can see this link that shows how to remove visual studio components left after an uninstall: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/

Comment: Hi MusicIsUniversal thanks its a helpful article but now I don't have issue of uninstalling problem is that how i start working because visual studio didn't responsing

Comment: I got it I also had a problem with launching Visual Studio 2015 and I thought I uninstall it completely from my PC but realized later that some cached files of the application still existed so I uninstalled it by force and it worked, maybe not completely uninstalling it might be a problem. Does it freeze completly and you have to stop the application? Check this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703139/visual-studio-freezes-or-hangs-on-startup it might be helpful for you, if it didn't work let me know again

Comment: Thanks  dear its resolve the issue. Its my first question so i don't have enough repetitions to vote you, so sorry for this but thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome and glad to hear your problem is solved. It's okay no problem! :)