# Visual studio community 2015 launch is not working proper

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed visual studio 2015 community edition after installation i click on the launch button and a white screen displaying about 30 minutes, the image is  also attached, whats the problem why its taking so much time.

[image]

Comment: Machine too slow? White screen is normally when your CPU is maxed out or the process is stuck waiting for resource,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try un-install and re-install. Otherwise let it run overnight, perhaps your system is really slow :).

But a quick search suggests that other people have had this trouble, even in previous versions of VS:

[Visual Studio freezes or hangs on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703139/visual-studio-freezes-or-hangs-on-startup)

[MSDN: Visual Studio hangs on Startup](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e9d804c-6868-4e26-b144-7ea77de2cc59/visual-studio-hangs-on-startup?forum=vssetup)

Otherwise post a dump of the VS Activity log, this is a file the VS generates at startup and maintains during execution

[Visual Studio log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809430/visual-studio-log-file)