# Useful Visual Studio Extensions For New C# Developer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to developing in C# in Visual Studio.  While I realize that this question might be a bit subjective, still, what are the most useful extensions out there for a new C# developer using Visual Studio 2012?  When I say useful, I mean tools that could guide me to writing better code, point out potential bugs, auto-correct, etc.  Tools that would allow me to write better and clearer code while adhering to the style and naming conventions of C#.

As I grow as a C# developer, I feel that I would probably start getting irritated with such auto-correcting tools, but right now it would be really useful.  I downloaded Resharper and that seems to be pretty cool and does what I'm talking about.  I have also looked at other extensions in the Visual Studio Gallery, but there are so many and it becomes a bit overwhelming.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks,
Justin

Comment: Please note: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: "Move Line Command", RemoveCAPS, "Color Theme Editor"

Comment: I understand, I really do. If left untended this could grow into a spam garden. However, I don't know what tools are available and what C# programmers use, especially for a new C# developer. I just need some training wheels. I have seen other threads but they are old and there is no extension guide that I was able to find. I have tried a few tools, but there should be clearly useful tools that practically all C# developers have or start out with. I also would argue that responses to questions are always opinionated as there is usually 50 different ways to accomplish the same programming goal.

Comment: @Justin: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757357/visual-studio-2010-recommended-extensions) here. It contains a lot of useful information. And is the first link when you Google "useful Visual Studio extensions". Don't let the fact is says 2010 fool you. The majority of those work in 2012 as well.

Comment: Ah, excellent! Also, much to my chagrin, I found this [link](http://jiripik.me/2012/06/02/recommended-best-visual-studio-add-ons-and-extensions/).  Which I believe gives a good list of extensions.

Answer (score 4):

I recently fell in love with [Flow](http://www.flowextension.com/).

Apart from that some people would suggest Resharper while others don't. I belong to the first category.

Comment: woah!  This is awesome!

Comment: I like ReSharper but it's quite noticeably impacted performance for me, though it could have to do with the fact that I develop on virtual machines.

Comment: @tnw for what it's worth, with a fast machine I didn't notice that much of a slowdown. ReSharper is all but lightweight, but if at all possible, get hold of an SSD drive. That really helps.

Answer (score 2):

First : [Resharper from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), (paid) this tool totally increase coding speed and are simply comfortable. If you're familiar with InteliJ or PyCharm - you'll feel like home.

Second : I recommend using [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) from Microsoft.

And for manage packages and libraries [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/)